# Why the checkbox `checkall` not mark/unmark the othersboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Why the checkbox `checkall` not mark/unmark the others `checkboxes`

https://jsfiddle.net/5s3krtLv/

```
<div ng-controller="ContactMessagesController">
    <input ng-click="MarkCheckBox()" id="checkall" class="mangerTdLabel" type="checkbox" />
    <table id="usersTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type=checkbox class=checkBoxJs1 />
                <input type=checkbox class=checkBoxJs1 />
                <input type=checkbox class=checkBoxJs1 />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


app.controller('ContactMessagesController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {


$scope.MarkCheckBox = function () {
        $('#usersTable').find('.checkBoxJs1:input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: check console for error. app is not defined in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `ng-model` and `ng-checked` directive

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="ContactMessagesController">
      <input id="checkall" ng-model="active" class="mangerTdLabel" type="checkbox" />

        <table id="usersTable" >
             <tr>
             <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="active" class="checkBoxJs1"  /> 
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="active" class="checkBoxJs1"  />
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="active" class="checkBoxJs1"  />

            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5s3krtLv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to not use JQuery to perform functions like this to modify the DOM; instead you should try to accomplish as much of this as you can with Angular.

Here's an example of how you could accomplish this with Angular:

**Controller**

```
$scope.checkAll = function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.checkboxes, function (obj) {
      obj.selected = $scope.selectAll;
    });
  };
```

**View**

```
<p>Check all</p>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
    <br />
    <p>Checkboxes</p>
    <div ng-repeat="checkbox in checkboxes track by $index">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox.selected" />
      <label ng-show="checkbox.selected">Checkbox {{ $index+1 }} selected!</label>
    </div>
```

[And here's the working plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ma3RFaAmjoJnajlnid5q?p=info)